# Javascript XMLHttpRequest Response for preflight error

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to do a simple get request using pure javascript, I haven't done that in a while. I have to pass a basic authentication to get this request. it works great in postman, the UI makes it simple to just enter user pass an go. What am I doing in the code that is giving me this "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status" error? Am I not setting up the requestion correctly? I am using the chrome cross-origin extensions and is turned on. So don't think that's the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="data">

    </div>


<button onclick="dashboard()">click me</button>
    <script>

        function dashboard() {
            var request = makeHttpObject();
            // var form_id = BO.getDataId();
            // var app_id = app.getUID();
            var user = "blah";
            var password = "blue"
            var app_id = "f4asdsd4sasdgrer5e78b-fcsdasssd77s-4ef4-8asefxzxcze207be8";
            var link = `https://found.mainstream.org/authentixate-basic/secure/1/data/${app_id}/F_Form1`;

            request.open("GET", link, true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user +":"+ password));


            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState == 4)
                    getAttachmentInfo(request.responseText);
            };
            request.send(null);


            function makeHttpObject() {
                try {
                    return new XMLHttpRequest();
                } catch (error) { }
                try {
                    return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (error) { }
                try {
                    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (error) { }

                throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
            }

            function getAttachmentInfo(data) {
                var parser, xmlDoc;

                if (window.DOMParser) {
                    parser = new DOMParser();
                    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
                } else {
                    // Internet Explorer 
                    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.async = false;
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(data);
                }
                for (i = 0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("F_Form1").length; i++) {
                    // var FilesObj = {
                    //     "attachmentFileName": xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("F_Attachment")[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue,
                    // }
                    //console.log("data",xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("F_Form1")[i].attributes)
                    console.log("data",xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("F_Form1")[i].attributes[3])
                }

            }
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: probably need to set up a proxy on server you control.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a CORS issue. code worked great in the production environment but wasn't in my local